# Is there any better way to write math in latex other than $latex **$

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, latex, plugin-mathjax

Question is as in the title.

Is there any better way to write math in latex other than writing $latex (some code here)$?

This is annoying.

Is there any better way to do this?

I see that theorem environment does not work in latex..

Can you suggest some thing?

I have added necessary plugins and $latex x^2$ is giving me x^2 in math mode.. No problem with that.

Comment: I'm afraid wordpress.com questions are off topic here. You should try their [help support](https://en.support.wordpress.com/) instead.

Comment: I have asked there... Waiting for reply.. May be you can also do me some favour if you know any thing about this @birgire

Comment: sorry, but I  don't know the LaTeX implementation on wordpress.com

Comment: Ok that is fine @birgire

Answer (score 0):

There are several other ways to do this, but these will give you a slightly different result, namely, that your equations will be centered on the page, and will appear in a new line.
The methods:

1. Write the equation between `\ [ \ ]`.
2. If you use the equation enviroment, your equation will be automatically numbered, so that you can refer to it later. Just write `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`    at the beginning and ending of your equation and you should be fine.
3. In case you want to write an integration or derivaton, the eqnarray enviroment is the best choice, wite `\begin{eqnarray}`, and `\end{eqnarray}`. This will also give a number to your equation, but you can delete that with `\nonumber` after the equation.

If you don't want your equation to "stand out" of the lines of the text, then using `$$` is the only way to do it.